# Distribution heavily stacked on either limit - appropriate test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, nonparametric, skewness, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I have two sets of results from an experiment that produces distributions with extremely heavily stacked sides and mostly uniform elsewhere. The aim of my analysis is to answer a the question roughly put like this : "With what degree of certainty can I say that the difference between Results A and Results B are not due to noise in the measurement/system"

The Wilcoxon Rank-Sum produces a **highly** significant p-value although one would expect that this is coming solely from the fact data A is more stacked at zero than data B. It may be the case that the distributions are significantly different but I was wondering if there might be a more appropriate test than the Wilcoxon Rank-Sum test given the shape of the data?

```
x
x
x                          x
x                          x
x                          x                                       
x                   x      x                   x
x                   x      x                   x
x                   x      x                   x
x                   x      x                   x
x     x   x x       x      x   x   x   x   x   x
x x x x x x x x x   x      x x x x x x x x x x x
x x x x x x x x x x x      x x x x x x x x x x x
0-------------------1      0-------------------1 
     A                               B
```

In the actual data the sides are even more heavily stacked than in the diagram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to test if two samples came from the exact same distributoin, the you can use the nonparametric [Two-sample KS Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov-Smirnov_test#Two-sample_Kolmogorov.E2.80.93Smirnov_test). It assumes the underlying distribution is continuous.

Another option for esting quality is the [permutation test](http://faculty.washington.edu/kenrice/sisg/SISG-08-06.pdf), where you pool both samples into one large sample and cycle through all possible ways of dividing it, each time calculating your test statistic. P-value is just the number of permutations that generate test statistics at least as extreme as the one you got using the actual samples for each.